How to make a disconnected GCS fully connected
When I create my GCS using iris builder and some seed states, I sometimes end up with a graph that isn’t fully connected.
My current solution is to find the disconnected nodes, and for each one iterate through the nodes on the connected part of the graph. Then, find the geometric mean of the centers of that node and the connected node and use that as the seed for the next region, and repeat this until the graph is fully connected:
    def bridge(self):
        max_bridge_per_region = 3
        disconnected_regions = set()
        give_up_regions = set()
        while disconnected_regions != (
                disconnected_regions := (set(self._get_disconnected_regions()) - give_up_regions)):
            log.info(f"disconnnected regions are {len(disconnected_regions)} many")
            if not disconnected_regions:
                log.info(f"bridging is done, had to give up on {give_up_regions}”)
                return
            region = list(disconnected_regions)[0]
            connected_regions = set(self.iris_regions.values()) - (disconnected_regions | give_up_regions)
            bridge_count = 0
            for cr in connected_regions:
                region_q_sample = region.MaybeGetFeasiblePoint()
                cr_q_sample = cr.MaybeGetFeasiblePoint()
                bridge_seed = np.mean([region_q_sample, cr_q_sample], axis=0)
                Log.info(f"bridge seed is {bridge_seed}”)
                try:
                    self.GenerateRegion(f"bridge_{uuid.uuid4().hex}", bridge_seed)
                    bridge_count += 1
                    if bridge_count > max_bridge_per_region:
                        break
                except Exception as e:
                    log.error(f"error in generate: {e}”)
                    continue
            if bridge_count == 0:
                log.info(f"giving up on region {region}”)
                give_up_regions.add(region)

This naive approach ends up working, but it’s  very slow! I was wondering if there is a more standard approach for creating these “bridge” regions when some of the existing regions don’t have intersections with others and the graph ends up being disconnected?

I would imagine that the approach you're suggesting is going to take many iterations to get everything connected, right? Here are a couple things you might try that could speed this up. (Although without knowing all the details, it's a little tough to make assurances.)

Check that the edge connecting the centers of the two regions is collision-free. If the edge is not collision-free, then it's probably not worth trying to make a region to connect them. You can either do the checking manually, or if you have a CollisionChecker object, you can use CollisionChecker::CheckEdgeCollisionFree method.
Make an initial hyperellipsoid that covers the entire edge connecting the two regions, and use that as the initial guess for IRIS-NP. If that hyperellipsoid is collision-free, then it will be contained in the polyhedron that the algorithm produces. (You may have to force IRIS-NP to terminate after a single iteration, as the hyperellipsoid changes in subsequent iterations.) Checkout IrisOptions for details -- you'll want to work with the starting_ellipse and iteration_limit fields for this. Just make sure the hyperellipsoid is "thin" around the edge.
Use the new IrisZo algorithm, and leverage the containment_points option to force the region to contain the two points. This is a very new feature (just got added to drake last week), so you'll have to build from source or use the nightly build.

There's definitely a lot of other things you could try as well -- constructing a good set of regions for GCS is an active topic of research for us. So please let us know if any of these things work for you!


Just make sure the hyperellipsoid is "thin" around the edge.

You can make such an object by calling AffineBall::MakeAffineBallFromLineSegment and then converting it to a Hyperellipsoid using its constructor from AffineBall.

thanks @sadra,
I see MakeAffineBallFromLineSegment in the docs, but I can't access it from pydrake (I tried both 1.35.0 and the nightly version 0.0.20241201)! My guess is that its not ported to python here?:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/geometry/geometry_py_optimization.cc#L190

If you make a feature request in the GitHub issues, I'm sure one of us can get around to adding the bindings soon.

Thanks @Thomas Cohn,
Created the feature request:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/22250
I’ll also be more than happy to get more involved and commit some code. (That is if Drake accepts contributors from outside TRI).
I’m also still tuning my enhance_GCS_connectivity function based on your feedback (so far so good)! I think when I have it right, it might be useful to add it somewhere for others too since I’d assume this would be a common use case. Will update here when it’s done.

Drake definitely accepts (encourages!) outside contributions. You can find some more information on how to contribute here.

Thank you for being a contributor to the Stack Overflow community. As a question and answer site, Stack Overflow works differently than most message boards. As such, kindly reserve the Answers feature for actual answers, not follow-up comments.
